# Make a Vaadin panel caption center aligned & scrollable

Tags: vaadin, panel

I'm trying to make a Vaadin panel caption center-aligned.

```
Panel panel = new Panel("Summary");
panel.setSizeUndefined();
addComponent(panel);
```

How do I make it so "Summary" is in the center-top of the panel?
Note: It's already at the top, but is default at top-left.

Bonus question: How do I make it so it's scrollable when I make the window smaller?

Comment: Please share more code. Where do you add your panel to? Window does not have addComponent method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will make your content scrollable and center your title. You can also do the same thing by adding a style to the panel using [addStyleName](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractComponent.html#addStyleName%28java.lang.String%29)

```
public class MyWindow extends Window
{
    private String longText = "halloween halloween halloween halloween "
            + "halloween halloween halloween halloween halloween halloween "
            + "halloween halloween halloween halloween halloween halloween halloween halloween "
            + "halloween halloween halloween halloween halloween halloween halloween";

    public MyWindow()
    {
        Panel panel = new Panel("<center>Summary</center>");
        panel.setSizeFull();
        panel.setContent(new Label(longText));
        setContent(panel);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you know where I can get a list of all the things I can do like <center>,<bold>,<h1>, etc?

Comment: Panel constructor can receive html content. So every piece of html code is allowed there. Take a look here http://www.w3schools.com/html/